# Excluding character from string not working

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex to validate a string: `^[A-Za-z]{2}([A-Za-z]|[0-9]){8}[0-9]{1}$` https://regex101.com/.

I'm trying to exclude a character `O` from the middel part, so I added `[^O]`:

`^[A-Za-z]{2}([A-Za-z]|[0-9][^O]){8}[0-9]{1}$`

But that doesn't seem to do the trick, what am I missing?

Comment: @anubhava can `[A-Za-z]|[1-9]` not be replaced by `[A-Za-z1-9]`?

Comment: Ehm I think your're missing the question :). I'm trying to exclude the `O` character from the middelpart of the string.

Comment: Please add some valid and invalid matches to make it more clear

Comment: valid `AA1234BX7Q1` invalid `AA1234OX7Q1` replaced the `B` with an `O`.

Comment: I had a confusion between `O` and `0` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without using any lookahead, just by using range inside character class:

```sh
^[A-Za-z]{2}[A-NP-Za-z1-9]{8}[0-9]$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U70Pch/1)

`A-NP-Z` range will match upper case letters `A-Z` except letter `O`.

Comment: Is there a reason why looking ahead is not preferred?

Comment: There are couple of reasons. Not every regex flavor supports lookahead and more importantly it is grossly inefficient here. Just check demo link in my answer that takes `20` steps to finish and when you copy/paste lookahead regex `^[A-Za-z]{2}((?!O)[A-Za-z0-9]){8}[0-9]$`  it takes 114 steps (almost 6x slower)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
^[A-Za-z]{2}((?!O)[A-Za-z0-9]){8}[0-9]$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/EpoEgi/1)